# ASP.NET ObjectDataSource SelectParameters CookieParameter question

Tags: asp.net, cookies

If my cookie is set like this:  Response.Cookies("Employees")("UserID") = 43

How do I get this value from within an ObjectDataSource SelectParameters CookieParameter?

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsProducts" runat="server" TypeName="MyCompany.Products" SelectMethod="GetAll">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:CookieParameter CookieName="????" Name="UserID" Type="Int32" />
     </SelectParameters>        
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I'm assuming that I would need to do something like this?

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsProducts" runat="server" TypeName="MyCompany.Products" SelectMethod="GetAll">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:CookieParameter CookieName="Employees.UserID" Name="UserID" Type="Int32" />
     </SelectParameters>        
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal, but you could set the ObjectDatasource's Parameter DefaultValue in the code-behind
odsProducts.SelectParameters["UserId"].DefaultValue = Response.Cookies["Employees"]["UserID"]

there may be an syntax error in there.

Comment: Yeah, I do this all the time, just though there might be a better way that I didn't know about that used the design-time controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom control to solve this problem. Kevin Isom's blog has a blog entry. 
[Custom Parameter for a DataSource](http://weblogs.asp.net/kevinisom/archive/2007/09/01/custom-parameter-for-a-datasource.aspx)